# What is the black part in the Lyx window?

Tags: lyx

Just some very basic questions as a new user...
What is that black part under the pink part of the Lyx window?
Can we change the pink color? Can we remove the black part? Why can't we use "Enter" to skip lines?

The screenshot is as follows. It's the newest version. OS is windows vista.
You can see the pink and black parts.

[image]

Comment: ah....screenshot? version? OS?

Comment: You might be interested in Tools > Preferences > Editing > Control > Scroll below end of document. As far as why no return, you can sometimes do "ctrl+return", but the reason is because in LaTeX extra whitespace does not mean anything (it does not add extra space in the document). If you really want to have LyX allow you to do this, you can set `FreeSpacing` and `KeepEmpty` to true in the Standard layout (read Help > Customization for more detail). Again, this is not recommended.

Answer (score 6):

The pink part of the window seems to be your actual document.  As you type more contents into your document, it will stretch, and eventually there will be no black part.  The black part is there just to fill in the part of the window not yet taken by the document.

As far as the pink color, I am not sure why is that.  It is white on my computer.  You can go to Tools->Preferences->Colors and change the background color.